# Tweenjs undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, box2d, tween, createjs

I'm creating a small game where the player needs to catch a mouse, currently I am stuck at the point of making the mouse flee to it's hole. This is my code:

```
var contactListener = new Box2D.Dynamics.b2ContactListener;
contactListener.BeginContact = function(contact) {

    var fixA = contact.GetFixtureA().GetBody().GetUserData();
    var fixB = contact.GetFixtureB().GetBody().GetUserData();

    // If ball hits mouse
    if ((fixA == "Mouse" && fixB == "Ball") || (fixB == "Mouse" && fixA == "Ball")) {
        console.log("Ball hits mouse");
        // if ball hits trap
        }else if ((fixA == "Trap" && fixB == "Ball") || (fixB == "Trap" && fixA == "Ball")) {
        // mouse x is between the edges of the trap
        if ((m.getX() > t.getX() -50) && (m.getX() < t.getX()+50)) {
            console.log("mouse captured!");
            }else{
            // if mouse isnt fleeing yet
            if (!mouseFleeing) {
                // mouse is fleeing
                mouseFleeing = true;
                var targetX = h.getX();
                console.log("mouse escaped!");
                // animate mouse to hole, but it doesnt work
                createjs.Tween.get(m, {loop:false}).to({x:targetX}, 1000);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Currently, I get the following error in my console (though the console log of the mouse escaping is working):

Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function. tweenjs-0.5.1.min.js:17

Am I misusing the Tween function?

Answer (score 0):

Either get() is not a method of Tween or to() is not a method of whatever get() returns. Sorry, I'm not familiar with Tween, I'm just speaking in general javascript terms. Look at the definitions of those functions/methods and make sure they are in fact members of the objects you think they are.

Comment: They both should be used according to the documentation http://www.createjs.com/Docs/TweenJS/classes/Tween.html and also used a youtube video which explains a lot: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OWHJa0jKJgo

Comment: Run the unminified version of Tween and see what line number the error happens on and throw that function up here.

Comment: Also something else I do when I'm perplexed by an error is try to reduce the problem area to the simplest example possible. Maybe cut the to() off and only give get() the first required parameter. Then if that performs unexpectedly, add to it until something goes wrong.

Comment: Great suggestions, I will bear them in mind for future issues. Unfortunately none of them seemed to solve or change the error.

Comment: The code looks fine at a first glance. You can see the code working fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/L4F8m/  - I agree that you should try it with the unminified version (the latest GitHub has a combined lib now), and check out where the error happens.

Comment: Hi Lanny, thnx for your response! I donwloaded tweenjs-0.5.1.combined.js and I now get the following error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined on the same line as my tween and also: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < on line 6 of tweenjs-0.5.1.combined.js

Comment: Removing the .get in the tween results in a Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function error

Comment: Do you need to call Tween from createjs? In the examples I peeked at they were calling Tween without referring to createjs. But I don't know how your imports/global variables are set up.

Comment: What happens if you simply call Tween.get(m) ?